# Making intermediate CTE results available for output/query without reprocessing earlier CTEs

Tags: postgresql, cte

Say I have the following query:

```
WITH
    d AS
    ( SELECT x, y FROM test WHERE x > 0 AND y > 0
    )
  , sc_x AS
    ( SELECT AVG(x) av_x, AVG(y) av_y FROM d WHERE x >= 5
    )
  , sc_y AS
    ( SELECT AVG(x) av_x, AVG(y) av_y FROM d WHERE y >= 5
    )
SELECT
    SUM(sc_x.av_x)+SUM(sc_x.av_y)+SUM(sc_y.av_x)+SUM(sc_y.av_y)
FROM
    sc_x
  , sc_y
```

Let's pretend those calculations are super complex and make sense to have in separate CTEs (I know these aren't). I need to query each of the CTE results and the final results for output for a program. I am thinking the best way to do this is to remove the CTEs and do SELECT ?? INTO like this for each CTE:

```
DROP TABLE d IF EXISTS;
SELECT x, y into d FROM test WHERE x > 0 AND y > 0;
DROP TABLE sc_x IF EXISTS;
SELECT AVG(x) av_x, AVG(y) av_y into sc_x FROM d WHERE x >= 5;
DROP TABLE sc_y IF EXISTS;
SELECT AVG(x) av_x, AVG(y) av_y into sc_y FROM d WHERE y >= 5;
SELECT SUM(sc_x.av_x)+SUM(sc_x.av_y)+SUM(sc_y.av_x)+SUM(sc_y.av_y)
FROM
    sc_x
  , sc_y;
```

Then query these tables separately. Is that the best strategy? I don't see another way to make the CTE results available without recalculating them. Speed is an issue, so I don't want to do all of the processing again that occurs before the CTE I want for output. Hopefully that makes sense.

PostgreSQL CTE page:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

I have Postgres 9.6.

Comment: What do you mean by recalculating?  That the result set of a CTE is once built, and if you query it twice, it's built twice?  This latter is not the case.

Comment: Thanks for helping. The context is that I always need the final results/select. If I also want CTE sc_x for output and I don't do the Select Into stuff, I have to run the query for CTE d and CTE sc_x over again. In the real world these take a long time. So creating the intermediate tables using Select Into makes all of the results available...but doing it with the select intos I have to create a bunch of tables, which is a bit messy in my opinion.

Comment: Well, if performance is really a matter, a bit of mess in the code cannot hurt :)  Otherwise, you can create those tables as temporary ones, adjust `work_mem` and `temp_buffers`, wrap the whole thing in a function and hopefully done.  Otherwise, seeing an actual execution plan of your query could help coming up with better ideas.

Comment: Okay, thanks. Yes, I was trying to focus the question on preserving (should have used that word in the question) the CTE results for output later. Sounds like the best way is to just select ?? into. Thanks!

Comment: These are all made up for simplicity. You can ignore the actual queries. My question is focused on what I can do with CTEs. Building out my Postgres functionality kb. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but: it is recommended to use `create table new_table as select` instead of the non-standard `select ... into new_table ...`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - how would the syntax work for that? I got `with my_cte as ([query here]) select * into new_table from ...` to work, but not `with my_cte as ([query here]) create table as select ...`